# Change period of MongoDB TTL expiration check

Tags: mongodb

With regards to document expiration based in TTL index [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/#timing-of-the-delete-operation) says:

> The background task that removes expired documents runs every 60 seconds. As a result, documents may remain in a collection during the period between the expiration of the document and the running of the background task.

Is there a way of changing that period by configuration? Or it is hardwired in mongod code?

Answer (score 5):

As of today, it's not possible, but already tracked in [MongoDB JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org):

- [`SERVER-6712`](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6712): *Make TTL Collection background task period user defined (command line option)*
- [`SERVER-8616`](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8616): *Adding Tunable to TTL Collection thread*
- [`SERVER-13937`](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13937): *Allow setting a window and interval for the TTL monitor*

There's also kind of a workaround - you can turn TTL monitor off and on manually:

```
db.adminCommand({setParameter: 1, ttlMonitorEnabled: false});
db.adminCommand({setParameter: 1, ttlMonitorEnabled: true});
```

**EDIT:** It turned out, that there is a `ttlMonitorSleepSecs` flag. It's mentioned for example [here](http://hassansin.github.io/working-with-mongodb-ttl-index#ttlmonitor-sleep-interval), but it's not mentioned in the official docs.

```
db.adminCommand({setParameter: 1, ttlMonitorSleepSecs: 60});
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! In http://hassansin.github.io/working-with-mongodb-ttl-index#ttlmonitor-sleep-interval I found `db.adminCommand({setParameter:1, ttlMonitorSleepSecs: 3600});`. What do you think about this command? Is not working in the current MongoDB versions?

Comment: Well, I couldn't find it in the official docs, but there's [`SERVER-30388`](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-30388) (affects version 3.0), which states that it should be positive. Have you tried it? If it'll work, I'll surely update my answer (and definitely use it by myself).