# MongoDB TTL does not works

Tags: mongodb, ttl

I work on debian 10(buster) with mongod ver. 4.2.17. I want to use TTL to remove older documents on collection. I do walk around and I'm sure that no typo on the query.

I followed dummy example offical mongo on [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/tutorial/expire-data/#field-is-array-of-dates) link, where create index on timestamp and expireAfterSeconds.

`db.log_events.createIndex( { "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 30 } )`

I Also added documents on collection with this

```
db.log_events.insert( {
   "createdAt": new Date(),
   "logEvent": 2,
   "logMessage": "Success!"
} )
```

but still not work. I do read that the logs not immediately on [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/timeseries/timeseries-automatic-removal/#timing-of-delete-operations) but after wait for some hours its still not deleted. Also on mongo logs, there's no TTL log appear. I do checking the indexes with `db.log_events.getIndexes()` and they do appear.

[image]

Any suggestion how to solve it?

Comment: check whether the index is created or not

Comment: @deadshot I updated the question, the index appear on the collection

Comment: try setting `expireAfterSeconds` to 0, check if it works

Comment: It's still the same. the document still not deleted

Comment: `db.log_events.getIndexes()` - what is the output? Is the TTL index listed?

Comment: @DhodyRahmadHidayat try with  old date as `createdAt`

Comment: @prasad_ the question already updated for this query

Comment: @deadshot the documents still not deleted

Comment: if you have docker try with mongodb docker image

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the same collection and the database?

Comment: @prasad_ I'm sure doing this in the same db and collection

Comment: If you delete the index, and then recreate it, do the symptoms remain?

Comment: @rickhg12hs yes, the TTL still not works. I made the collection and the index many times but it's still not works. I'm wondering whats could make this happen, I thought it was something I have to add to config files or something I must put on mongo, maybe (?)

Comment: Is this a time series collection?  If so, it has its own expiry parameter.

Comment: Weird that `db.log_events.getIndexes()` shows `expireAfterSeconds` is a `Double`.  Maybe try dropping the index and create it again while making sure `expireAfterSeconds` is an integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I trying to find whats wrong with the mongo, then I tried to activate TTL thread with this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51061352/change-period-of-mongodb-ttl-expiration-check)

```
db.adminCommand({setParameter: 1, ttlMonitorEnabled: true});
```

Then I tried to using this [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54132903/the-ttl-process-of-mongodb-passes-0) command to check whether the thread are running or not with `db.serverStatus().metrics.ttl` and return as

```
{ "deletedDocuments": NumberLong(0), "passes": NumberLong(0) }
```

also using the `db.adminCommand ({getParameter: 1, ttlMonitorEnabled: true})` and return `was: true`.

**It's solved by re-install the mongo** on the machine and when check the serverStatus() again it works like a charm. Still dont know whats the problem but reinstall fixing my issue.